# Python code to identify and separate specific number from a text string

Tags: python, csv, data-analysis

I have a dataset of text messages from users.

I would like to analyze the financial health of users based on their bank balance from the text messages.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rmegm5eEHFHhueGIsGxs13-tuXnHT6aILmIpuEysHVw/edit?usp=sharing

I have already wrote a python script to isolate debit and credit transactions from the overall dataset (sample dataset is already cleaned with just debit and credit data)

```
Your SB A/c *9571 Credited for Rs:1 on 05-05-2022 18:32:45 by IMPS ref no 212518273773 Avl Bal Rs:4813.87 -Union Bank of India
```

I would like the available balance part of each messages separated so i can analyze them.

Im stumped can you please direct me in the right direction please

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use `pandas` to load the CSV and use regular expression to find available balance. For example:

```py
import pandas as pd

# data.csv is your data from the question:
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", header=None)
x = df[0].str.extract(r"Avl Bal Rs:([-\d.]+)|Avl\. bal\. is Rs (-?\d+\.?\d*)")

df["Available Balance"] = x.apply(
    lambda x: x.loc[idx] if pd.notna(idx := x.first_valid_index()) else None,
    axis=1,
)

# print sample output:
print(df.head(10).to_markdown())
```

Prints:

|  | 0 | Available Balance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Your SB A/c *9571 Credited for Rs:1 on 05-05-2022 18:32:45 by IMPS ref no 212518273773 Avl Bal Rs:4813.87 -Union Bank of India | 4813.87 |
| 1 | A/c *9571 Credited for Rs.5000 on 05-05-2022 11:55:30 by Mob Bk ref no 212585053128 Avl Bal Rs:5011.87 -Union Bank of India | 5011.87 |
| 2 | Congratulations! |  |
|  | Your A/C No. XXXXXX Can Be Credited up to Rs 1 Lakh. |  |
|  | Submit Your Details for Approval: am9.in/s/lDw0rG4SNt |  |
| 3 | Rs.1000 credited to your account 6281424237. Time to Shop Your Faves on LimeRoad! Valid on 10% order value. limeroad.com/u/d567abde - Limeroad |  |
| 4 | A/c *9571 Debited for Rs.100 on 01-05-2022 09:13:24 by Mob Bk ref no 212177022310 Avl Bal Rs:23.87 -Union Bank of India | 23.87 |
| 5 | A/c *9571 Debited for Rs.20 on 30-04-2022 17:14:34 by Mob Bk ref no 212060765507 Avl Bal Rs:273.87 -Union Bank of India | 273.87 |
| 6 | A/c *9571 Debited for Rs.4200 on 30-04-2022 15:25:39 by Mob Bk ref no 212059808844 Avl Bal Rs:293.87 -Union Bank of India | 293.87 |
| 7 | A/c *9571 Credited for Rs.3000 on 30-04-2022 14:29:03 by Mob Bk ref no 212019498831 Avl Bal Rs:3493.87 -Union Bank of India | 3493.87 |
| 8 | A/c *9571 Debited for Rs.10 on 30-04-2022 10:32:36 by Mob Bk ref no 212027851969 Avl Bal Rs:493.87 -Union Bank of India | 493.87 |
| 9 | A/c *9571 Debited for Rs.200 on 29-04-2022 20:07:13 by Mob Bk ref no 211979590457 Avl Bal Rs:503.87 -Union Bank of India | 503.87 |